# Как оптимизировать tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

Есть система которая позволяет распознавать документы через api, построено api на flask.
Документ делится на 4 части и каждая из частей документа обрабатывается параллельно с помощью multiprocessing.Process.
В каждой из частей происводится поиск текстовых полей, эти поля обрезаются и отправляются в цикле на распознавание тессеракту.

Возникает большая нагрузка на ЦПУ при одновременном запросе 2-х и более документов. Как можно оптимизировать работу тессеракта?

Comment: Ну сделайте однопоточную очередь обработки у tesseract )

Comment: @CrazyElf Обязательно нужно использовать многопоточность, т.к иначе скорость распознавния будет низкой

Comment: Ну не знаю, я бы проверил разные варианты. Судя по нагрузке на CPU tesseract может уже внутри себя многопоточно фигачит и лишней нагрузки ему не надо. А вообще надо смотреть, может его можно под GPU оптимизировать, например.

Comment: Внутри тессеракта многопоточность уже убрал, установив переменную OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = 1